# Single-page wordpress theme navigation

Tags: query-posts, homepage, wp-list-pages

I'm trying to build single-page theme. I want user to navigate thru menu with anchors (for example `<a href="#About">About</a>`).
I've extended Walker for wp_list_pages so it outputs anchors instead of permalinks. How to bite it now? I thought I will use `query_posts` for `'post_type' => 'page'` and just style those pages but is there more flexible way of doing this? Also this query displays all pages (all I want is just depth = 1) and I don't know how to order them same way as wp_list_pages does.

Maybe there is some text to read about this kind of pages on the internet?

Comment: Static pages really don't lend themselves well to the infinite scroll/lazy load implementation. That technique works well for *blog posts*, because they are *chronological*, and all relate to one another on the basis of chronology. Static pages, on the other hand, are entirely stand-alone, have no chronology, and have no other means of correlation one to another.

Comment: @ChipBennett I don't like this kind of pages neither but that's not my idea and I simply have to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a few templates that essentially are on one page. I used this code as the starting block for all of them:

```
<?php
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page','posts_per_page' => -1));
    foreach ($all_wp_pages as $value){
        $post = get_page($value);
        $slug = $post->post_name;
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
   };
?>
```

It basically gets every page, you can then use the variables to build the rendered markup.

Then a small change to meet you're depth requirement I would use:

`$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page','depth' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => -1));`

And finally `'posts_per_page' => -1` gets everypage, not limited to the number set in 'Admin > Settings > Reading'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I found out that `depth` doesn't work here. I've used `'post_parent' => 0` instead and it works fine. The last but not least problem is ordering. How to order pages same way they are ordered by `wp_list_pages`?

Comment: ahh i did do this too... let me dig it out.

Comment: try `'order'=>'ASC'`

Comment: Tried already that and `orderby` and I still don't understand logic here.

Comment: I've sorted `wp_list_pages` using `sort_column => menu_order` and now I have what I need. Thanks